Avoid multiple array to list conversions to create a logarithmic scale with linear subdivisions
Is there a way to create a log scale with linear subdivisions with less conversions between lists and numpy? The multiple changes lead to errors when treating a list as an array or vice versa.
def log_linsub(start, end):
    'Creates a log scale from 10**start to 10**end with linear subdivisions.'
    base = np.array(range(1, 10))
    seq = [base*10**val for val in range(start, end)]
    seq = list(np.array(seq).flatten())
    seq.append(10**end)
    return np.array(seq)


Perhaps you can go into why you'd want a 'more pythonic' solution? Is there some aspect of the code that you hope improves? If you focus on that aspect, the question won't be as open to interpretation - and is less likely to get closed on account of asking for opinions.

Sure! What I don't like is the necessity of converting a range to an array concatenated as a list that needs to get flattened turned into a list and then into an array. It feels like too many bounces between array and list. In particular, if I'm not careful tracking when the sequence is an array or list, I might get errors because I'm trying to operate on an array as a list or vice versa.

def log_linsub(start, end):
    "Creates a log scale from 10**start to 10**end with linear subdivisions."
    return np.unique(
        [
            base * 10**val 
            for val in range(start, end) 
            for base in range(1, 11)
        ]
    )

explaining some of the refactoring:

since you have a iteration over range(1, 10) and range(start, end) it's possible to change it into a list comprehension, making it more legible and pythonic;
the reason you have the last code snippet is caused due to range not being inclusive at the end of it, which that would cause some value duplicate eg. 100 & 1000 values at start=1, end=3 but you can deduplicate by using np.unique (if a np.array is needed) or set(...)


Beautiful! I'm surprised python doesn't have something like this built-in (or at least, easily accessible!)

if you are using numpy, then consider broadcasting. eg (np.arange(1,11)*10**np.arange(start, end)[:,None]).flatten()

@Onyambu That's what I had done in my answer. It's much faster (since it's pure numpy).

This can be done pretty easily (and quickly) using numpy.
def log_linsub(start, end):
    a = np.arange(start, end)[:,None]
    b = np.arange(1, 10)
    c = 10**a*b
    return c.ravel()

For clarity, here are the intermediates when calling log_linsub(1, 5):
a
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]]

b
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

c
[[   10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90]
 [  100   200   300   400   500   600   700   800   900]
 [ 1000  2000  3000  4000  5000  6000  7000  8000  9000]
 [10000 20000 30000 40000 50000 60000 70000 80000 90000]]

Speed tests:
>>> %timeit log_linsub_original(1, 5)
10.3 µs ± 621 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
>>> %timeit log_linsub_original(1, 1000)
3.89 ms ± 8.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %timeit log_linsub_tiov4d3r(1, 5)
13.1 µs ± 288 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
>>> %timeit log_linsub_tiov4d3r(1, 1000)
11.7 ms ± 33.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


>>> %timeit log_linsub_mine(1, 5)
3.23 µs ± 11 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
>>> %timeit log_linsub_mine(1, 1000)
18.2 µs ± 137 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

So, about 3 times faster for small inputs and 200 times faster for larger inputs.

This is the best solution.  its the answer I would have given.

@Onyambu Thanks. I posted it after the accepted answer was already accepted, so it seems to have gone mostly unnoticed.

I really appreciate that this answer is faster by far. The other answer is a bit more readable to me, and in my application readability trumps speed, but I will definitely agree that at this point it is a question of preference. If I could mark both as answers, I would!
